# SlideUp on a form not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Take a look at [**this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dj2Y8/)

I increased the duration to `2000` to exactly show you what I am talking about. When you click the close (`X`) the animation is not what one would call `slideUp`. I was expecting that the form would move upward until it fully disappears. Instead, it hides from bottom to top slowly.

Is the `slideUp` expected to behave like it is? Or is it something that I did?

I am guessing its because of this part of CSS (line 15)

```
.js-enabled form {
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this behaviour you are expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/dj2Y8/2/

Comment: It's the [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)...

Comment: I edited the question to explain it better. And no, I was not talking about the form overlapping the `h1` and `p`

Comment: I was thinking of making `top: -100%` and then when `slideDown` starts, form would **move** down form `-100%` but sadly that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal behaviour for `.slideUp()`. From [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/):

> The `.slideUp()` method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide up, appearing to conceal the items.

Or to paraphrase, it is the elements below the one being hidden that will appear to slide upwards. But in your case because you had `position:absolute;` the elements below had more of a "reveal" effect than a slide.

You can get the element itself to actually slide if you use the [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the `top` of the element:

```
.animate({top : -$this.height()-100}, 2000)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dj2Y8/4/

For purposes of the demo I simply animate the `top` to a sufficiently negative position that it moves off the top of the window, easy enough when the element is at the top of the page though `-$this.height()` wasn't quite high enough so I arbitrarily subtracted an extra `100`. Obviously you'd need to tweak this if the element wasn't at the top of the page, perhaps animating several CSS properties at once.

Comment: Ok now I understand it! Thanks for your help :)
But is there a way that I can achieve the **moveUp** and **moveDown** motion?

Comment: I commented before you updated your answer :) I was reading `.animate()` docs.
It works great. Thanks for help @nnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

Even though you had `slideDown` under the `config`, you were using `fadeIn` under `init`. I also changed the `2000ms` (2 seconds) to `500ms` (1/2 second). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dj2Y8/3/ 
jQuery `slideUp` essentially animates the `height` of the element to `0px` and hides it; so yes, it is working how it should.

Comment: I intentionally changed duration to `2000` to show that its not actually sliding up, Its kinda hard to see that at `500`.
Thanks for your help `+1`